# Failing to store the Timestamp PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, timestamp

In my entity I have a column as followe :

```
@CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Timestamp createdDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

On calling save method of dao it is throwing :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid date type
```

In database type of the timestamp is stored as `timestamp without time zone`

How should I specify this type in annotations ?

Comment: Why you don't easily use `Date` instead?

Comment: @YCF_L20 Works for java.util.Date not for java.sql.Date weird thanks